# Set GTK theme by launch a program by $GTK_THEME env

Tags: linux, fedora, environment-variables, themes, gtk

There are https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK+ talk about that I can set GTK Theme manually for individual launched program so:

> $ GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark gnome-calculator

It's work. But how can I to know so Adwaita:dark but not Adwaita_dark or not Adwaita-dark ?
How can I get all available theme (list) that can apply so?

I try  for Nokta theme set:

```
$ GTK_THEME=Adapta:nokta gnome-calculator
$ GTK_THEME=Adapta_nokta gnome-calculator
$ GTK_THEME=Adapta-nokta gnome-calculator
```

Not work`s

Answer (score 2):

Themes are stored as folders in `/usr/share/themes/` and optionally in `~/.themes/`.

You can simply get their names by running `ls /usr/share/themes/ && ls ~/.themes/` in the terminal.